# DocumentDb CreateDocumentQuery stopped working

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of our documents
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<T> List(string query)
{
    // Return our items
    return this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(this._databaseName, this._collectionName), query).ToList();
}
```

which has been working fine up until today.
Now it throws an error:

> Partition routing information cannot be extracted from the query when running in a 32-bit process. To complete your query and avoid this exception, ensure that your host process is 64-bit.\r\nFor Executable applications, this can be done by unchecking the \"Prefer 32-bit\" option in the project properties window, on the Build tab. \r\nFor VSTest based test projects, this can be done by selecting Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture as X64, from Visual Studio Test menu option.\r\nFor locally deployed ASP.NET Web applications, this can be done by checking the \"Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects\", under Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Projects.\r\n

which is really odd, because nothing on my end has changed.
I tried doing everything it said, but to no avail, it still has errors.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you try to change your host process to 64 bit?

Comment: yeah, and it works, but why has this changed? This was working fine the other day

Comment: May be someone else changes it or your machine configuration is changed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some information about this error message can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/140).

If you do not use the partition routing feature in DocumentDb you can change your code to provide `FeedOptions` to disable `EnableCrossPartitionQuery`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of our documents
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<T> List(string query)
{
    // Return our items
    return
        this
          ._client
          .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
               UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(this._databaseName, this._collectionName), 
               query,
               new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false };
          ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: That is not working for me. Still getting this error using Azure DocumentDB.